# RabbitMQ remote error connection to Lightsail (Ubuntu instance)

Tags: rabbitmq, amazon-lightsail

I have this urls RMQ options which works fine on local MacOs machine

```
{ urls: ['amqp://127.0.0.1'] }
```

Then I installed RMQ on a remote machine at AWS Lightsail (Ubuntu) and opened the necessary ports

```
Custom  TCP  5672
Custom  TCP  15672
```

I successfully logged in remote UI with previously created new user credentials

```
http://my.com:15672
```

But any of this configs are not work for remote RMQ server connection for data passing.

```
{ urls: ['amqp://my.com'] }
{ urls: ['amqp://my.com:5672'] }
{ urls: ['amqp://login:password@my.com'] }
{ urls: ['amqp://login:password@my.com:5672'] }
{ urls: ['amqp://2.50.11.117'] }
{ urls: ['amqp://2.50.11.117:5672'] }
{ urls: ['amqp://login:password@2.50.11.117'] }
{ urls: ['amqp://login:password@2.50.11.117:5672'] }
```

I have this error

```
 [Nest] 90314  - 01/26/2024, 5:59:47 PM   ERROR [ClientProxy] Disconnected from RMQ. Trying to reconnect.
 [Nest] 90314  - 01/26/2024, 5:59:47 PM   ERROR [ClientProxy] Object:
{
  "err": {
    "errno": -54,
    "code": "ECONNRESET",
    "syscall": "read"
  }
}

 r(new Error("Channel ended, no reply will be forthcoming"));
```

Please help resolve this issue.